# Access Azure web app web service through AAD using MSI

Tags: java, azure, rest, authentication

I have an Azure webapp (App Service) running with Tomcat. I'd deployed 2 war applications. WAR-1 provides web service call which return a json files using Springboot. WAR-2 is a web application which call this web services in WAR-1. This webapp has system assigned managed identity (or MSI). In addition, this webapp has authentication on with AAD, using Express configuration.

I can access static pages in WAR-2, after authentication through AAD. Now I need to fetch data from WAR-1. I have a servlet which contains code like this:

```
String subscriptionId = "xxxx";
String testURL    = "https://yyy.azurewebsites.net/war1/person/100";
String resourceId = "https://management.azure.com/";

AppServiceMSICredentials credentials = new AppServiceMSICredentials(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
Azure azure = Azure.configure()
                .withLogLevel(LogLevel.BODY_AND_HEADERS)
                .authenticate(credentials)
                .withSubscription(subscriptionId);
String token = credentials.getToken(resourceId);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(testURL).openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
....
```

I do able to get a token, but the response code is 500 when I make the GET call.

So my question is ... is this the correct way to do this call ?  I did found an articlehttps://dotnetdevlife.wordpress.com/2018/10/22/call-azure-ad-protected-website-using-managed-service-identity-msi/ similar to this situation but it uses .Net.  I cannot find any Java equivalent of this.

Comment: The resourceId  is not correct. You set it to `https://management.azure.com/`, then the token can only be use to call azure management API.  If you want to call your web api, you need to set it to its client id.

Comment: Thanks ! Using client ID works perfectly.

Comment: May I know if you still have anything unclear with this question? I have post my answer blow for your reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested at my side, and here are my steps:

#### 1. Two apps in one Azure web app.

App1: `https://jackdemoapp1.azurewebsites.net/app1/`

App2: `https://jackdemoapp1.azurewebsites.net/app2/`

#### 2. Configure Authentication/Authorization on Azure portal.

[image]

And you can get the client ID by clicking into the details, note it down and we will use it in app2:

[image]

#### 3. Configure managed identity on Azure portal

[image]

To simplify the test, the app1 will just return a "Hello" string.

[image]

#### 4. Code in app2

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        try {
            AppServiceMSICredentials credential = new AppServiceMSICredentials(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
            // As we want to get token for accessing the aad-protected app, change the
            // resource to the client ID you get in step 2
            String token = credential.getToken("ac07d701-6f7d-462e-8b67-5dffa1df955f");
            json.put("token", token);

            // The URL for app1 API
            String app1 = "https://jackdemoapp1.azurewebsites.net/app1/";
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(app1).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            // Open the connection
            conn.connect();

            int code = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (code >= 200 && code <= 300) {
                try (InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = "";

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line);
                    }

                    String response = stringBuilder.toString();
                    json.put("response", response);
                }
            } else {
                json.put("Error", "Response Code" + conn.getResponseCode());
            }
            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            json.put("Exception", e.getStackTrace());
        }
        return json.toString();
    }
```

---

### Result

[image]